# Rails 4 not using Remotipart to remotely submit form

Tags: jquery, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, ajaxform, remotipart

It looks like Remotipart isn't actually being used to submit my form, so the image is completely left out when I look at the params where the form gets submitted to.

`remotipart_submitted?` returns false

params: `{"utf8"=>"✓", "product"=>{"name"=>"RemotipartFails", "price"=>"10", "description"=>"Please work"}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"products"}`

Below is more relevant code

### Gems

```
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "remotipart", "~> 1.2"
```

### Javascript

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.remotipart
```

### Form

```
<%= form_for(:product, url: products_path, remote: true, html: { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
  <div class="margin-top-10 margin-bottom-10">
    <div class="input-left">
      <%= f.text_field :name, { placeholder: "Name", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="input-right">
      <%= f.number_field :price, { placeholder: "Price", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix margin-bottom-10"></div>
    <div class="input-full">
      <%= f.text_field :description, { placeholder: "Description", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix margin-bottom-10"></div>
    <div class="input-full">
      <%= f.file_field :image, { class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix margin-bottom-10"></div>
    <%= f.submit "Add Product", class: "btn btn-green" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I've tried it without the `multipart: true` because I think form_for adds it automatically, but that didn't help.

At this point I'm open to alternative solutions (hopefully allowing me to submit the form remotely with an image still)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? i'm running into the same issue. :(

Comment: @SwaathiK Not quite, I added an issue on their Github but they never responded. I offered an alternative library there: https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/issues/109

Comment: Great! Thanks. But I just tried with remote true without any gem. I have jquery file uploads though. And it just seems to work. The form submits via AJAX. Is this correct?

Comment: I am facing same issue and tried whatever suggested in https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/issues/109. I am still far from the solution.

Comment: Ok, I don't know why there is no answer in the github issues but this seems working for me when trying with exact same fields as in question with Rails 4.2.6. @TMP can you check if it's working for you? or let me know what can I do to show that it's working?

Comment: @BrianRusselDavis Feel free to follow up in the issue. People there have had the issue much more recent than I. I recommend moving away from it anyways due to the lack of response by the maintainers

Comment: Hi, actually, I was facing the same issue, I used Remoteparti gem but the page is still loading while uploading. Then, I used to upload the image through iframe technique [see here](https://www.alfajango.com/blog/ajax-file-uploads-with-the-iframe-method/). This will not reload the page.

Comment: Have you tried adding `data: {type: :json}` to your `form_for` tag? I'm using carrierwave and remotipart to ajax create/update records with images and adding that was the magic that got it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow code working for me to submit the form via ajax with image. Even though its form_tag, It can be easily changed to form_for syntax.

```
<!--In View-->
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery_ujs", "jquery.remotipart"%>

<%= form_tag({:controller=>controller,:action=>action},{:method => 'post' ,:name=>'upload-data',:id=>'upload-data', :multipart => true, :target =>'upload_frame' }) do -%>
          <!--Form fields here-->
<%end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#upload_frame").load(function() {
   var responseText = $("#upload_frame").contents().find('body').html();
   if(responseText != ""){
     $("#element_to_update").html(responseText);
   }
 });
</script>
```

I hope this will be useful to someone facing issue.